# Animations into pdfLatex from After Effects

Tags: animations

How would I go about forming animations in Latex? Is it possible to make animations or embed videos **without having to use Adobe Acrobat etc?** Essentially, I have an animation if Adobe After effects and was wondering if it is possible to embed this into pdfLatex (I am using TeXWorks) without needing to use Adobe Acrobat to view it. I have tried converting it into a png sequence through Adobe media encoder but I don't know where to go from there. I have heard of the `animate` package, but don't we need to use Adobe Acrobat to utilise it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The result of the compilation of a .tex file with pdflatex is a pdf file, therefore you must use some kind of viewer for pdf files to see the resulting pdf file.

Comment: Once you have a set of numbered PNG files, you can embed and animate them with pkg `animate`. Okular or Acrobat Reader are needed for viewing.

Comment: I have a list of png images as follows: Comp-000.png, Comp-001.png, Comp-002.png, ... , Comp-311.png. How would I code that into Latex?

Comment: From the documentation of `animate`: "PDF files with animations can be viewed in Acrobat Reader (except on mobile devices), KDE Okular, PDF-XChange and Foxit Reader." So you don't have to use Adobe Acrobat it seems (but it isn't supported by all viewers).